# Behaviour with `repeated_permutation` and floating points

Tags: ruby, floating-point, permutation

I'm solving Project Euler problem 33.

```
(10..99).to_a.repeated_permutation(2) do |ary|
  print (ary[0]/ary[1]).to_f if ary[0]/ary[1] < 1
end
```

returns nothing but a series of decimal places and zeros. However if I take the values of the array and divide them manually, for instance:

```
print 98/99.to_f
```

the correct value is returned.

Can anyone explain why this happens, and (more importantly) how to circumvent it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `ary[0]` and `ary[1]` will always be positive integers inside your block. That means that `ary[0]/ary[1]` will be `0` or some positive integer. Your block does nothing when `ary[0]/ary[1]` is less than one (i.e. when `ary[0]/ary[1]` is anything other than zero). Since you only call `print` when `ary[0]/ary[1] == 0`, you're really just saying:

```
print 0.to_f if ary[0]/ary[1] == 0
```

This:

```
print 98/99.to_f
```

prints what you're expecting but you're not doing that in the block, you're saying things like:

```
print (98/99).to_f
```

and we see that the `to_f` call is in the wrong place.

You're probably trying to say:

```
print ary[0]/ary[1].to_f if ary[0]/ary[1] < 1
```

to get floating point division rather than integer division.